# Is there an JS API for Office 365 to operate paragraphs, tables or text in a Word document?

Tags: office365

Is there an Javascript API for Office 365 to operate paragraphs, tables or text in a Word document?

I want to use the API to search for some certain text/field in the document and replace them.

Comment: Search for API / library is off-topic in Stack Overflow. Try Google / MSDN.

Comment: Already done but no good result.@Raptor

Answer (score 0):

One option is to get the document as [ooxml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj715284.aspx), then use [openXml](https://openxmlsdkjs.codeplex.com/) to traverse and replace the objects.  Psudo code:

```
    function getParas() {
    var documentText = null;
    Office.context.document.getFileAsync("compressed", function (result) {
        if (result.status == "succeeded") {
            //Get the file
            var myFile = result.value;
            myFile.getSliceAsync(0, function (resultSlice) {
                if (result.status == "succeeded") {
                    //We got the file slice. Now we will encode the data and post to a service
                    documentText = OSF.OUtil.encodeBase64(resultSlice.value.data);
                    var doc = new openXml.OpenXmlPackage(documentText);

                    // Replace the first paragraph in the document with the new paragraph.
                    var allParas = doc.mainDocumentPart().getXDocument().descendants(W.p);
                    // .firstOrDefault().toString();

                    for (var i = 0; i < allParas.count(); i++)
                    {
                        var Para = allParas.elementAt(i);
                        var ParaText = Para.toString();
                        app.showNotification(ParaText);
                    }

                }
            });
            myFile.closeAsync();
        }
    })
}
```